# Software/system to create user-friendly relational database management system, similar to MS Access

Tags: open-source, database, web-browser, gui-builder, microsoft-access

We have a company that delivers educational programs to other companies. With excel sheets we register who is taking which course and how much they owe us, etc.

Every tab in the sheet is a different program and lists all instances of that program (different dates, locations and all the participants). And with formulas it keeps track of how much every student has to pay and what the costs are per instance and the overall costs and profit for every program.

It's time we upgrade the excel situation to something (preferably) web-based for registering all the participants and calculating loss & profit.

I'm ok with SQL, but I'm not getting paid enough hours to develop a system from scratch (in PHP for example). I've tried using SuiteCRM (and a couple other open-source crm systems) but found that querying income and costs per project was difficult.

I'd like to be able to make a decent user-friendly management system to register participants, costs, etc. and calculate our in- and outcome.
We are not looking for a Learning Management system. This is purely for the administration.

Comment: Whenever someone asks me for an Open Source alternative to Access I think Base https://www.libreoffice.org/discover/base/

Comment: I think that you should make it clear that you are looking for a billing app, not that you intend to implement a databases.

Comment: I know native PHP is too much for this project, but have you consider a php framework like lavarel?  It hides most of the fiddly coding, takes care of security, and generally simplifies the process.

Comment: @Mawg - Well I want to create something like a billing app. By making use of a db management system. (Don't overlook the word 'management') So I still intend to use a database.

Comment: @cybernard - I will look into lavarel, thanks for the suggestion.